# Subquery in 2 different time column

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I tried this but it said that **ERROR: subquery must return only one column**

```
 Select date_trunc('week', kyc.kyc_verify_date::timestamptz) as "week",
        COUNT(*) filter (where kyc.status = 4) AS "A1",
        COUNT(CASE WHEN kyc.status = 5 
              THEN 
                   (Select date_trunc('week', kyc.last_update_time::timestamptz) AS "week",
                        count(*) filter (where kyc.status = 5)
                    From kyc
                    Group by 1)
              END) AS "A2"
from KYC 
Where kyc.kyc_verify_date >= date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '4 week') 
       and kyc.kyc_verify_date < date_trunc('week', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
Group by 1
```

i do this query to get the result that if `status = 4` will take the date is `kyc_verify_date`,

but if `status = 5` will take the date is `last_update_time`

What should I have to change in this query? or is there any way better?

Answer (score 0):

A `case` expression returns **a single value**. Since you need 2 values from it you will need to repeat the expression.